# How to formulate this integer constrained optimization over multiple variables in Scipy?

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy

I've the following constrained optimization problem (pic attached). Basically, given values N, T, F, I've to do an optimization over variables n, q, k, where all the variables are integers.
I'm having a hard time to formulate it over SciPy. In particular, how can I encode the constraints in my problem ?

[image]

Comment: Scipy doesn't provide a solver for integer programming problems. Instead you could try the [mip](https://www.python-mip.com/) package to model and solve your problem. It ships with the CBC solver by default.

Comment: @joni You may want to show how this can be formulated as a linear MIP problem.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Ups, this is indeed the more challenging question. I guess the OP might have more luck on [OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/) or [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am not sure this is linear at all.